# How to use mkdir-touch

Tags: command-line

Hello again Ubuntu users

I'm trying some new things with mkdir and I can't quite get the hang of things

I want to learn how to make a directory inside of a specified path, then a touch.txt text document with words inside or a story

So far I've got

```
 mkdir ~/Desktop/new_file touch ~/Desktop/new_file/adas.txt
```

But that doesn't work, and not sure how to get words in it all from one command line

Answer (score 1):

This could be done this way:

```
mkdir ~/Desktop/new_file && touch ~/Desktop/new_file/adas.txt && echo "Hello World" > ~/Desktop/new_file/adas.txt
```

Information:

1. `&&` This ensures that the command preceding it executes correctly before the next command, hence if the preceding command fails the next won't execute.
2. `>` Directs the output of the echo command into the `adas.txt` file.

Comment: I don't see a > in your code

Comment: look at the `echo` bit...

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using `mkdir --parents` (or `mkdir -p` for short) to avoid an error if the directory already exists (you can also create nested directories this way, e.g `mkdir -p dir1/dir2/dir3` will create the requested directories and not throw an error if they already exist).

You may also want to consider omitting the `touch` command entirely as `>` will create the file for you if it doesn't already exist (FYI: `>>` will append to the end of an existing file, wheras `>` will overwrite an existing file.

So,

```
mkdir -p ~/Desktop/new_file && echo "Hello World" > ~/Desktop/new_file/adas.txt
```

Should do what you want, then you could later do things like:

```
echo "More text to add" >> ~/Desktop/new_file
```

More info can be found in the bash manpage (`man bash` under **SHELL GRAMMAR** (particularly the **Lists** section.

Good Luck